# How do I execute "use dbname" over Oracle dblink to Sybase?

Tags: oracle, sybase, dblink

How do I access tables in my user schema in Sybase from Oracle?

In `isql` I can do

```
use mydb
go
```

How do I select from `mydb` tables from Oracle using dblink `NITSYB5`?

This does not work:

```
select count(*) from  "mydb"."lon_client_confirm_exec"@NITSYB5;
```

Error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
[Oracle][ODBC Sybase Wire Protocol driver][SQL Server]"mydb"."lon_client_confirm_exec" not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).
 {42S02,NativeErr = 208}
ORA-02063: preceding 3 lines from NITSYB5
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 30
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I don't work with Oracle and hence know nothing about Oracle's dblink, so fwiw ...

In Sybase ASE the fully qualified table name format is: `<dbname>.<owner>.<table>`

If you leave out the `<owner>` then the optimizer will first look for tables owned by the user running the query, then look for tables owned by `dbo`.

In your example it appears you've left out the `<owner>`.  If the table is owned by your user or `dbo` then I'd suggest you try adding an additional period, eg:

```
select count(*) from mydb..lon_client_confirm_exec@NITSYB5;
```

NOTE: Add quotes as/if needed by Oracle's dblink.

Answer (score 0):

SERVER 1 AND SERVER 2
open SSH server2 telnet server 1 host, its ok to done
su oracle

```
1) cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
2) TNSPING database1 name
```

its ok done

```
create public database link 
  LINK_NAME
connect to 
  DB1USERNAME
identified by 
  111 
using 'DB1NAME';
```

`select * from dual@LINK_NAME, result x,` finish.